# overriding class in spring

Tags: java, spring, components, overriding

We have a spring boot projects which use external jar

```
 @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"book.lib", "lib.author"})
  public class BookServiceApplication {
  }
```

We would like to override existing component which exist in the external jar.

```
 book.lib.model.refresh
 @Component
 public class BookRefresher {


 public loadBooks() {
     System.out.print.ln("External Jar");
 }
```

I would like to add different implementation to BookRefresher while I am not able to do changes in the external jar.

In my project BookServiceApplication -

1. in application.yaml

   ```
    spring:
       main:
       allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
   ```
2. Added the new implementation

   ```
    book.lib.model.refresher

    @Component
    @Primary
    public class NoBookRefresher extends BookRefresher {


    @Override
    public loadBooks() {
      System.out.print.ln("No Implementation");
    }
   ```

But seems both of the components are running and no override is being applied.

Comment: When you said both a running. 
What is happening ? NoBookRefresher  is called and BookRefresher  is called after ?

Comment: @Ruokki Exactly.